# Avoid page reload when browser back button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQXwidgets, something like the following [from here](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/jquery-grid-paging.htm). As seen in `Image #1`, I am on the `91-100` section of the list which is last. Suppose I click on first record which is `Regina` I will move onto next page in my website. However, 
when I click the browser back button, it reloads the page and I am back to the first list with `1-10` as shown in the `image #2`

**Questions:**

Is it possible with the browser back button to land on the same list `91-100` where `Regina` name is listed? Or do I need to add back button and do what to achieve that? Please advise. Thanks

**Image #1:**
[image]

**Image #2:**[image]

Comment: images won't help. please add code

Comment: It's certainly possible; use [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries). How you implement that in to your code is anyone's guess as you've not shown it.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need some javascript that cancels the event.

```
<script>    
history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
   window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
   history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
});
</script>
```

try that?

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try this. So this would work after adding a back button or it should work with the browser's back button as well?

Comment: Specifically this hijacks the event for the browser's back button. My assumption was that you were working on a single-page app. A common theme in software development is never to override system behaviours, but this code will do what you asked.

Comment: Yes, it's a single page app. Thanks. Let me try and see how it goes.

Comment: I used the exact same code but the back button isn't working at all. It's not going back at all. However, commenting out the code brings back the normal working functionality of back button.

Comment: Apologies, it's meant to function as an example. Yes all it does is stop the back button event. You will need to put code to do something else underneath the history.pushState(..); line.